# SSRS on Microsoft Edge Browser Windows 10

Tags: reporting-services, windows-10, ssrs-2012, microsoft-edge

When browsing to SSRS 2012 on the Microsoft Edge browser in Windows 10 I get this error:

> Hmm, we can't reach this page.
>
> Try this
>
> Make sure you've got the right web address: http:// ipaddress of SSRS server
>
> Refresh the page
>
> Search for what you want

SSRS works fine using IE 11 which is pre installed on Windows 10 but if MS are phasing out IE I need to use SSRS with Microsofts preferred browser. Any ideas what this could be?